# Rails 3 cucumber display webrick debug output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber + capybara and when I run `rake cucumber` I get fancy cucumber scenario output in terminal.

But when I run app with `rails server` then I get various useful
debug info about controllers, views, sql, etc..

Is there any way to run cucumber and get rails debug output in addition to (or instead of) cucumber's one ?

Comment: Usually you dont need the debug information in your tests.. If you want to print out specific details you can write "puts {info}" in your steps.

Comment: I faced such situation now, there is server error happens under the hood and cucumber just hides it, so i just see wrong test results and have no idea why it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `rake cucumber`, controller activities will be logged to `log/test.log` or `log/cucumber.log` (this depends on your configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rake cucumber --backtrace` to get more verbose errors, but that'll still only show you where your cucumber code failed.  It won't display any Rails errors that resulted in your failed test.  You can get some info from `log/test.log` or `log/cucumber.log`, but that's still not the same output you would get if you could see the Rails standard out.